# What's the best way to write a custom format! macro?

Tags: rust, macros

I'm trying to create a custom `crash!` macro that essentially just wraps `eprintln!`, but it could be any other `format!`-like macro. It currently looks like this.

```rust
macro_rules! crash {
    ($fmt_str:literal, $($args:expr),*) => {{
        eprintln!($fmt_str, $args);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }};
}
```

I can't use `$args` directly as it's still repeating, so I need some way to break it apart, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your solution work, the best way to forward macro arguments is to capture them as `tt`. In your case, since all you want is to forward them, you can use `$($t:tt)*`:

```rust
macro_rules! crash {
    ($($t:tt)*) => {{
        eprintln!($($t)*);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }};
}
```

This has the advantage that it is completely transparent and enables everything the underlying macro enables. For instance, in this case, the `tt` version supports early-expanded format string, while your original version does not ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6cbbb95ea0ded4b4a86cb130e85ccecd)):

```rust
// crash!(concat!("a", "b")); // Does not compile
crash_tt!(concat!("a", "b"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was just having a mental blank, and ended up answering my own question. I just needed to expand `$args`... Just for anyone else who ends up here, the solution looks like this:

```rust
macro_rules! crash {
    ($fmt_str:literal) => {{
        eprintln!($fmt_str);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }};

    ($fmt_str:literal, $($args:expr),*) => {{
        eprintln!($fmt_str, $($args),*);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }};
}
```